# Data driven cells within a table

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, html-table

I am fairly new to ASP.net and this is my first post, so sorry if I do anything wrong.
I am currently trying to create a table that has 8 rows and 2 columns.
The main problem that I am having is that I need the data in the second column to be retrieved from a sql database using a specific sql query for each one.

I have tried this by having individual sqldatasources and adding a details view for each one in the second column and this worked, however because asp.net creates another table when you use the detailsview, it doesn't allow me to keep the same height that I had for the rows. The design space is fairly limited so this is important that I keep it as it is.

Can anyone suggest a fairly simple method of making this work please?
I am trying to replicate something that was done in classic asp, using VBscript and it seemed a lot simpler then.

Sorry if this is a really basic thing that I am missing, but I have looked for a very long time now and am still not finding anything I can use.

This is what I am trying to replicate (Just for the top cell)

```
lngNumRecs=0    
    rst.Open "SELECT COUNT(tblProject.Project_ID) AS NumRecs FROM tblProject INNER JOIN tblProject_Customer ON tblProject.Project_ID=tblProject_Customer.Project_ID WHERE (Type_ID=1 OR Type_ID=3 OR Type_ID=4) AND Status_ID=51", conn
    if rst.BOF or rst.EOF then

    else
        if isnull(rst("NumRecs"))=false then lngNumRecs=rst("NumRecs")
    end if  
    rst.Close
    .Write "<TR>"
        .Write "<TD>"
        .Write "<A href=/Orderbook/OrderSummary.asp?ListNo=1 target=_OrderSummary>"
        .Write "To be scheduled"
        .Write "</A>"
        .Write "</TD>"

        .Write "<TD>"
        .Write lngNumRecs
        .Write "</TD>"
    .Write "</TR>"
```

and I am trying to do this by placing the details view with its own sqldatasource in the table cell.

If I could simply link the results of the sql query to a label or something similar then that would be great, but I can't figure it out.